# How to access the properties of an object contained in an arraylist that is a property of another object

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to reference the properties of an object contained within an array list that is itself the property of another object.

here is a simple version of the code

Item class

```
public class Item {

    String name;
    String stat;
    int dmg;

    public Item(String name, String stat, int dmg) {
        this.name = name;
        this.stat = stat;
        this.dmg = dmg;
    }

}
```

Unit class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Unit {

String unitName;
int unitHealth;
int unitMoves;
int unitDmg;
ArrayList<Item> unitInv;

protected Unit(String name, int health, int dmg, int moves, ArrayList<Item> inv) {
    unitName = name;
    unitHealth = health;
    unitDmg = dmg;
    unitMoves = moves;
    unitInv = inv;
    }
}
```

Game class

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Item testItem = new Item("Test Item", "DMG", 10);

        ArrayList<Item> unitInv = new ArrayList<>();
        Unit unitObj0 = new Unit("Test Unit", 100, 10, 4, unitInv);
        unitInv.add(testItem);
    }

    public void getName() {
        for(int i =0; i < unitInv.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to figure out how I would specifically reference each of the properties of testItem contained within unitInv. I am wanting to code methods that access the properties of testItem and use them to modify the properties of unitObj0. The point of this is that I will be changing the items contained within unitInv and I will need to be able to write modular code that can access this same information regardless of the item or number of items contained within unitInv.

I have spent a lot of time messing with for loops but I don't understand how to get the loop to access the properties of testItem contained within unitInv not to mention I'm not sure that that would be the appropriate thing to do here. If there is a better modular way to do what I am trying to do here please advise with details if possible.

Comment: Can you also post what loops you have tried?

Comment: Right now im just trying to write a for loop that prints the name of the object testItem but all I can get is the hash location which I need to solve too. Beyond this I'm not sure how I would iterate from the outside to the inside loop which would target testItems properties.

Comment: It might help if you could add that code here, so that we can see what you have tried, and help you debug.

Comment: I have added it to the end of the game class

Comment: Here unitInv cannot be resolved? Im not sure how to fix this much less iterate further to determine the properties of each item contained within unitInv

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access every item in the `unitInv` list of the `unitObj0` object you can try this `for` loop:

```java
for ( Item item : unitObj0.unitInv ) {
    // use your individual item here 
}
```

This will allow you to access every `item` of the ArrayList `unitInv` which is a property of the `unitObj0`.

Answer (score 0):

So your code has the following issues:

1. `unitInv` is defined inside of `main`, hence, it cannot be reached outside of its scope. You must either declare it outside of the method or pass its reference to the method that you are calling.
2. I don't see where you are calling `getName` method, but I'm going to assume that it's inside of `main`.

Try this:

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Item testItem = new Item("Test Item", "DMG", 10);

        ArrayList<Item> unitInv = new ArrayList<>();
        Unit unitObj0 = new Unit("Test Unit", 100, 10, 4, unitInv);
        unitInv.add(testItem);

        getName(unitObj0);
    }

    public void getName(Unit unit) {
        for( Item item : unit.unitInv ) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So in this case I would simply contain the Sysout from getName as variables and then reference them elsewhere for my subsequent methods?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. `System.out.println()` prints to the console.

Comment: I'm saying I want to return these values I'm iterating so I can use them. For example I would want to return the int from testItem to add it to the value of 10 that is stored in unitObj0's parameters in some other method. How would I specifically get the int value back from unitInv in this way?

Comment: Also, the for loop above only returns this: Item@15db9742

Comment: @DarthBusiness It is printing the address of the object. You will have to override the `toString` method if you want to print the item. I left that there because I was following your example. If you want to return the items then you can just run the loop within the `main` method.

Comment: I know this might be a basic thing but could you please provide sample code for this?

Comment: @DarthBusiness Code for what? Overriding `toString`, or running the loop inside of `main`? Personally, I think I have answered your question.

Comment: Running the loop inside main